# "Unable to get value of the property 'style'" when trying to change style in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Have written a function for cycling through the questions in a online quiz. I works fine in every browser but IE (god I wish IE would just curl up and die). Function is below.

```
function cycleQs() {
var qs = document.getElementsByName("quizQ");
var nextQBtn = document.getElementById("btnNextQ");
var i = 0;
var curQ = -1;
for (i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
    if (qs[i].style.display == "block") {
        curQ = i;
    }
    //qs[i].style.display = "none";
}
var valid = false;
if (curQ > -1) {
    var qId = qs[curQ].id.replace("dv", "");
    var inps = document.getElementsByName(qId);
    if (inps.length > 0) {
        if (inps[0].type == "radio") {
            for (i = 0; i < inps.length; i++) {
                if (inps[i].checked) {
                    valid = true;
                }
            }
        } else if (inps[0].type == "hidden") {
            valid = true;
            for (i = 0; i < inps.length; i++) {
                if (inps[i].value <= 0) {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        valid = true;
    }
} else {
    valid = true;
}

if (valid == true) {
    for (i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
        qs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (curQ < (qs.length - 1)) {
        qs[curQ + 1].style.display = "block";
        if (curQ == (qs.length - 2)) {
            var scoreDv = document.getElementById("dvScore");
            nextQBtn.style.display = "none";
            var answers = getAnswers();
            //alert(answers)
            scoreDv.innerHTML = "Processing";
            processResults(answers);
        }
    } else {
        qs[0].style.display = "block";    // Problem occurs here when function first loads
    }
} else {
    alert("You must select an answer before you can proceed");
}
}
```

Any ideas of a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` is likely not returning anything, because of IEs implementation: [see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/b3eb3e22-4e91-46be-9b4e-94533d2ec350/)

so `qs[0]` probably doesn't exist